# Outlook 2016 "randomly" spins creating a new email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've got a brand new installation of Office 2016 on a brand new Surface Pro 4 running Windows 10. Several times a day when creating a new email or replying to an email I'll get the spinning icon and will never regain control of the message. I end up going into task manager and killing Outlook. Unfortunately I then lose the message that I was composing.

This is a plain vanilla installation of Office. I have not added any rules or add-ins.

Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

I've taken to using Thunderbird on other machines because it seems to be much more reliable and less quirky.

Comment: Are you connecting to an exchange server or IMAP/HTTP?

Comment: I am using IMAP.  This only seems to happen when creating or editing an email. At that point I would assume that there is no reason for it to talk to the server.

Comment: Try going into the COM add-ins section and unchecking every add-in, then try it again